# Is it normal for menus to be priced in grams in Venice, Italy?

Tags: italy, price, restaurants, venice, scams

I visited Venice recently. In one restaurant menus were priced in grams and not per portion. So this resulted in several times bigger bill when I have originally expected. **Is this type of pricing is standard in Italy or Venice?**

[image: Venice cheque]

Comment: Did this apply to all menu items or just seasonal food such as fish? You are showing your payment slip which is of very little aid, do you have your actual bill or the menu? Do you recall what the place was called and could you provide a link?

Comment: https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/4495484?m=19905 don't have a menu photo sorry. So this is normal for seasonal food?

Comment: Just found the same link. Looking at reviews it looks like you fell into a pretty bad tourist trap. Sorry for you but this kind of stuff happens in Venice...

Comment: I am assuming answer is yes then.

Comment: I'd rather say the answer is no. This is not typical. Just a bad place among many good and average ones.

Comment: Agree with @ptityeti. Did you have fish by chance or a steak, which can be priced by 100g also in other places? Besides from reviews they seem to have just high prices, a untypical 15% service charge and likely some other fees to rip you off.

Comment: Also self service buffet style can be by weight for obvious reasons.

Comment: Nope items were priced at ~15-20 Eur (per 100g) without portion sizes. So I assumed that portions are quite small. I had grilled calmari, lobster, seafood soup, and chicken.

Comment: Advice for the future: *never* go into a restaurant in a touristy place without first checking reviews online.

Comment: If the menu did not state explicitly that prices are in grams, then this amounts to fraud and you should call the authorities.

Comment: Whenever I have seen this kind of behaviour there **was** at the very least the weight for a single portion, so that you could make out the price you were paying.

Comment: Pro tip from an ex student in Venice: if you visit Venice, consider eating in a pizzeria/restaurant in Mestre (the part of Venice which is on the land side right after the bridge). Prices are more aligned to the normal Italian ones.

Comment: It certainly is common for fresh fish and expensive cuts of meat. I've eaten so many times in Italy without having a clue what the bill is going to be. Often they just tell you the dishes without even giving you a menu. love it :)

Comment: @Bent I'm Italian and I have lived in Italy for the most part of my life, so I have a general idea of what the law says. It seems unlikely to me that the police is in on this scam, but in any case pressing charges should be safe. It's not all godfathers and gangsters here, after all.

Comment: @Bent your comment is 100% nonsense: What about US law in Italy? You confuse the reality with your prejudices

Comment: @Bent you cannot really judge Italy without looking at the regional differences. There's a huge difference between a restaurant in Naples, where almost surely they are paying the pizzo to the mafia or else they get killed, and a restaurant in Milan or other northern cities where there isn't anything comparable as mafia. I highly doubt polixe is corrupted and had hands in criminal activities, at least in the north, at most they are closing an eye but if you go ahead and point this out they are probably going to move.

Comment: @Berwyn «Often they just tell you the dishes without even giving you a menu. love it» Refusing to communicate the prices is illegal in Italy. If they don't give you a menu, ask for it.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Nobody has ever refused to give me a menu!

Comment: @Berwyn the sentence I quoted is yours, isn't it? Moreover, if you *need* to ask for a menu rather than getting it by default, you already know that it's a trap. ;)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto It is. I know restaurants fairly well in Italy though. I don't eat in tourist traps. If I'm not sure of the place I will of course ask for a menu.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius the situation is simple (1) you were completely ripped off in a scam restaurant.  (2) yes, it's totally commonplace in Italy (and many, indeed "all", other countries) that at the very high end with prime steak and prime seafood you're charged by weight.  (A simple obvious example is any high end steak-joint in Florence.)  So to be clear, this totally scam restaurant tricked you by abusing that system. You know?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First of all, looking at the [reviews for Osteria da Nico on Tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/4495484?m=19905), regrettably you fell prey to a tourist trap.

Regarding your question on pricing by weight: such is typical for foods such as meat (e.g. a steak) or especially seasonal fish but very untypical for regular courses (such as e.g. a Pizza). You can find the menu of a reputable Italian restaurant [here](http://www.osteriacavalieri.pisa.it/en/menu.htm) (no affiliation) and will see that only T-bone steak and fresh fish are priced per 100g. I have encountered such pricing not only in Italy but all over the world.

Comment: I don't think I've ever read such poor reviews for a restaurant before. That's brutal.

Comment: heh you almost want to go to that place as a novelty!